# Is dynamoDB' item available for querying immediately?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I added some items to dynamoDB table using DynamoDBMapper.save. I then queried the item immediately. Will I definitely get the saved item? Or I should put thread.sleep() before querying the item? In SQL database, we use transactions and we can guarantee that we will get the item once the record is inserted to sql table. But for dynamoDB, I am not sure. Checked AWS dynamodb documents but didn't find related information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DynamoDB reads are eventually consistent by default. However, DynamoDB does allow you to specify strongly consistent reads using the `ConsistentRead` parameter for Read operations. It does come at a cost however, strongly consistent reads take up twice as much Read Capacity Units.

See: [Read consistency in DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html)

Comment: So you are saying, if we don't specify ConsistentRead=true we will probably not get the item which was just saved?

Comment: No there is indeed a chance that you wont get back the item that you expect. Behind the scenes DynamoDB consists of potentially many replicas, which need to be synchronized. That means that you can write to one replica A, and read from another replica B that was not yet synchronized with the write that happened to A.

Comment: That means if we need get sync'ed data, we can either: 1) set ConsistentRead=true; 2)wait certain time, for example a few minutes, till the items are sync'ed in all replicas.

Comment: DynamoDB is NOT an eventually consistent database. That is just the default when reading. What you are saying about replicas is not exactly correct either. DynamoDB only acks when it has been durably written to at least two AZs. Within miliseconds it will be in the third AZ. For regions with only two public AZs, there is actually a third non-public one. So if you do not specify a strongly consistent read AND you read an item in less than the replication then you could get a dirty read.